# How to use multiple filter lists (html-select) on one table to narrow down results without the conflicting?

Tags: javascript, html-table, html-select

I'm not a programmer but attempting to create a simple academic website. I have a host of articles in a table and managed to use some javascript and select-html to create a filter that works from W3 Schools. I am attempting to add a second select-html filter to narrow results further, but seems that only the first list will work. I've tried to add additional ids to differentiate the two lists, but likely doing it wrong and not working.

What I would like to be able to do is use the first filter to keep all Author1 instances, and if you choose to use the second filter to narrow down to Category1, it will result in all Author1 and Category1 if any (in example above, just top row would remain).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mylist");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="mylist" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control' style="max-width: 250px; min-width: 250px">
  <option></option>
  <option>Author1</option>
  <option>Author2</option>
</select>

<select id="mylist" onchange="myFunction()" class='form-control' style="max-width: 250px; min-width: 250px">
  <option></option>
  <option>Category1</option>
  <option>Category2</option>
</select>


<table id="myTable" height="100%" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Author1, Category1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Author1, Category2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version using

- addEventListener
- hidden
- map

It is possibly trickier than what you had hoped for, but it is using modern and recommended methods

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tbody tr"); // all rows with data
document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("change", function() { // any select change
  const filters = [...this.querySelectorAll("select")].map(sel => sel.value); // make an array of values
  rows.forEach(row => { // loop over all rows
    const string = [...row.querySelectorAll("td")].map(td => td.textContent.trim()).join(" "); // join the cell content
    const found = filters.every(filter => { // every filter is looked at
      if (filter === "") return true; // it could be empty
      return string.includes(filter); // if not return true if found
    })
    row.hidden = filters.join("") != "" && !found; // hide if something was selected and not found
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="filter">
  <select class='form-control' style="max-width: 250px; min-width: 250px">
    <option></option>
    <option>Author1</option>
    <option>Author2</option>
  </select>

  <select class='form-control' style="max-width: 250px; min-width: 250px">
    <option></option>
    <option>Category1</option>
    <option>Category2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<table id="myTable" height="100%" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Author1, Category1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Author1, Category2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Multiple

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#myTable tbody tr"); // all rows with data
document.getElementById("filter").addEventListener("change", function() { // any select change
  const selected = document.querySelectorAll('select option:checked'); 

  const filters = Array.from(selected).map(el => el.value); // make an array of values
  rows.forEach(row => { // loop over all rows
    const string = [...row.querySelectorAll("td")].map(td => td.textContent.trim()).join(" "); // join the cell content
    const found = filters.some(filter => { // every filter is looked at
      if (filter === "") return true; // it could be empty
      return string.includes(filter); // if not return true if found
    })
    row.hidden = filters.join("") != "" && !found; // hide if something was selected and not found
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="filter">
  <select class='form-control' style="max-width: 250px; min-width: 250px" multiple>
    <option>Author1</option>
    <option>Author2</option>
  </select>

  <select class='form-control' style="max-width: 250px; min-width: 250px" multiple>
    <option>Category1</option>
    <option>Category2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<table id="myTable" height="100%" width="100%">
  <tr><td>Author1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Author2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Author3, Category1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Category2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, this worked perfectly!! Quick question. Do you have a solution for <select multiple>. When I run multiple selections it doesn't seem to work. Perhaps the java is conflicting somehow with the ability of 'multiple' to work? Thank you kindly!

Comment: const selected = document.querySelectorAll('select option:checked');
const filters = Array.from(selected).map(el => el.value);

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Truly appreciated. If possible, could you show me how to add to your initial code provided? I'm still very novice and I've tried to integrate the line into each and every area I thought appropriate, but no luck. The closest I came allowed me to select multiple categories, but instead of displaying both, it hid both. Potentially being crossed up with the 'row.hidden =' feature? Again, thank you kindly for taking the time, much appreciated helping me learn!

Comment: This is how I tried to implement:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=dHQsKCVkJO

Comment: You can see how when applying multiple it hides both instead of showing both

Comment: Of course. You wanted to see if AuthorX AND CategoryY were present
https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/c02takhd/
Here you need to add Author1 AND Author2 to be able to use multiple select

Comment: Oh, so they must be included in the same row for multiple? <tr>Author1,Author2</tr>? My aim was for something like this: <tr>Author1</tr><tr>Author2</tr><tr>Author3,Category1</tr><Category2</tr>. If the user selected both authors 1&2 and only category1, then only the row containing category2 would be hidden, but the other three would be visible (even though category1 contains Author3. Essentially, show all rows containing the selected criteria. Hopefully that doesn't complicate matters too much?? This is way beyond my skill level, but I greatly appreciate your guidance if possible :)

Comment: Please see added example. I am not sure that is what you want

Comment: Brilliant!!! That is exactly what I was looking for!!! Thank you so much for helping so much on this to get to this solution. Honestly, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: I'm studying the differences between the versions to better my understanding on how you've achieved that, and it's starting to make better sense to me as well!